# Entity Framework Code First manual database changes not updating

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Maybe I'm defeating the purpose of Code First but for one reason or another let's look at the problem.
I'm working in EF Code First.  My 'Cars' POCO has a "Make" field,.. that matches the "Make" column in the db.  Now I come along and I manually rename the column in the db to "Manufacturer".   How can I force EF to catch up and update/ rename the POCO?

At the moment I'm using EntityFramework 6.1.3 and VS 2010.

Comment: You can drop the database and it will be recreated. Or look in to using migrations.

Comment: I am using migrations.  I have tried "Add-Migration ManuallyUpdatedDatabase" command but still this did not rename the property in the POCO.

Comment: Oh I misread your question. You are using code first which means you should change your *code* and let the migration rename the database column, not the other way round.

Comment: Ok but this time I'm a bold boy and the database was brought out of sync.  So how can I bring harmony back to the universe?   I was thinking of deleting all of my POCOs and doing a new rebuild from db but that seems like a hack.  Is there no elegant "rebuild-over write local" command?

Comment: Rename the column back to what it was, then do a proper migration.

Comment: That would be fine in this simple example but last night on a more complex project I simply could not figure out what was freaking the system out, an index or a foreign key.  The messages were a bit cryptic.  After trying to "change back the problem" I got lost in the attempts.  So the solution for me was to clean up the db manually and then try to re-sync EF.  
Seems like something that people would blunder onto often enough.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find to this problem of the database being out of sync with EF on the code side was to delete all of the MIGRATIONS and the ENTITIES poco classes, and on the db side delete the _migrations table.   Then go back to your application and add to your project a new "Code First from Existing Database".

This solved the problem for me easily and will allow me to work with Code First AND SQL Server Management Studio (as I like to do (until I get better at EF)).

I know it's a bit of a work-around but it'll get you out of jail if you find yourself in this situation.